# Ionic App not showing assets and ionic components properly on iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 3 app working in production on Android.

Now I just build the iOS version but I have a problem with the assets and some ionic components like `ion-input`.

**For example I expect to see that screens:**

[image]
[image]

**But, instead I got these:**

[image]
[image]

I already checked the absolute and relative paths for images but I don't have relative paths.
For example I have this type of paths:

```
    <ion-slide class="third-slide">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="corner-image" src="/assets/img/corner_plants.png" alt="corner">
          <img class="center-image" src="/assets/img/mariposa.png" alt="corner">
        </div>

        <div class="title-container">
          <h1 class="title">
            Regístrate para comenzar.
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="description-container">
          <ion-grid class="description-grid">
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-2 class="nav-button-column">
                <button class="previous" (click)="onPreviousButtonClick()">
                  <img src="/assets/img/icons8-chevron_left.png" alt="next">
                </button>              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-8 class="description-column">
                <p class="description">
                  Meditar te ayudará a cultivar la paciencia, mejorar tu capacidad de adaptación y liberar tensiones.
                </p>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-2></ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </div>

        <div class="access-buttons-container">
          <button class="register-button" ion-button block round (tap)="openCreateAccountPage()">
            {{ texts.btn_register }}
          </button>
          <button class="login-button" (tap)="openLoginOptionsPage()">
            {{ texts.btn_login }}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
```

And another weird thing is that the ionic components are not showing neither. You can see that the register page has three inputs and in the iPhone they don't appear. And I can't see the background image neither.

I researched about this but I could not find anything, because the most of the people only have problems with relative paths. I don't know what is the problem.

PD: Sorry for using images, but it's the only way I can share that.

Anyone can help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
The app works fine if, for example, I do login with facebook and navigate through it. It connects to firebase and then.. the problem is only that I mentioned.
In browsers works fine too.

Comment: The multiple times I have encountered this issue (android though) is because of adding that extra `/` in the assets path. Try using `assets/img/icons8-chevron_left.png`.

Comment: What @Adrian said is not enough. You need to go one folder back: `../assets/img/icons8-chevron_left.png`

Comment: Neither answer worked :(  still the same.

Comment: files are case sensitive in iOS and also on android. if you have changed the names recently, it might be because the files are still stored with an old name with different cases. If that's the case, I suggest you change the name completely to force iOS and Android to use the new file

Comment: I don't know how but I solved it. The problem was greater than simple assets, because it was not showing specific ionic components neither.
So, I reinstalled the platform, configured all the things in xcode (push notifications, pods, etc) in order to be able to run it on iOS, and the problem was solved.

Comment: And yes, like @Adrian mentioned, I had an extra `/` for images. Removing them works on iOS, but I had another problem. Now both are solved.